# Jedi Vim autocompletion fails

Tags: python, vim

After installing jedi-vim with Pathogen, I noticed that several features weren't working correctly. To test the behavior of jedi-vim, I copied the 2nd code snippet featured in the demo at https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim, and notice at least several important differences.

First of all, the autocomplete string is scrambled (see 1st screenshot, right above the cursor. The method signature is scrambled with the line above it, which reads "orz = getattr(asdfy()(), 'asdf')"
[image: scrambled autocomplete]

Second, the autocompletions don't recognize that orz should be time in the code snippet such that the code completion suggestions are completely off. (See second screenshot).
[image: Inaccurate completion suggestions]

I've disabled all of my plugins other than Pathogen, commentary, and jedi-vim and have basically cleared out my vimrc to prevent any interference. Does anyone have any ideas as to what might be causing jedi-vim to have this behavior?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I figured this would fall under "software tools commonly used by programmers"